# How do I install asciiquarium?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, perl, ascii-art

How do I install and run `asciiquarium` in Ubuntu?  It seems kind of complicated, and I don't know how to compile source code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

These instructions will work for Ubuntu 12.04 and later.

## **Install term-animation**

First, you need to install Perl module called term-animation. Open a command-line terminal by pressing CTRL+ALT+T.

First, type

```
sudo apt install libcurses-perl
```

This will install the program that will run `perl` scripts on your system.

Next, run

```
cd /tmp
```

to change your working directory to `/tmp`, this is the folder where temporary files are stored.

After you are in `/tmp`, you are going to have to download the source code for `term-animation`.  To do this, type

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/K/KB/KBAUCOM/Term-Animation-2.6.tar.gz
```

Extract the tarball you just downloaded by running this command:

```
tar -zxvf Term-Animation-2.6.tar.gz
```

Change your working directory to the folder you just extracted (NOTE: if you ever forget where your working directory is, simply type `pwd`).

```
cd Term-Animation-2.6
```

Next, you are going to run the perl script "Makefile.PL"

```
perl Makefile.PL &&  make &&   make test
```

(The `&&` operator separates commands)

Finally, we can finish installing `term-animation` by running this command

```
sudo make install
```

## **Download and install Asciiquarium**

Once again, we are going to change our working directory to `/tmp`.

```
cd /tmp
```

Now we are going to download the `perl` script that runs `asciiquarium`.

```
wget --no-check-certificate http://www.robobunny.com/projects/asciiquarium/asciiquarium.tar.gz
```

Extract the tarball you downloaded.

```
tar -zxvf asciiquarium.tar.gz
```

Now change the working directory to the folder you extracted.

```
cd asciiquarium_1.1
```

Next, we need to copy the `perl` script to `/usr/local/bin` where all of the executable commands are.

```
sudo cp asciiquarium /usr/local/bin/
```

Finally, to be allowed to run `asciiquarium`, you need to give yourself permission to execute the `perl` script.

```
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/asciiquarium
```

## **Running asciiquarium**

To watch `asciiquarium` in your terminal, simply type

```
asciiquarium
```

[image: Asciiquarium v1.1]

Simply press CTRL+C to stop the animation.

Comment: Instead of building `Term::Animation` yourself, you might just run `cpan -I Term::Animation` (uppercase i), and later `perl -I ~/perl5/lib/perl5 asciiquarium` (also uppercase i)

Answer (score 16):

No compiling is required as there is a PPA that I believe is run by a Debian developer dedicated solely to `asciiquarium`. Open a Terminal window and paste the following two commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ytvwld/asciiquarium
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install asciiquarium
```

And then the application is yours to run:

[image]

Enjoy :)

**Note:** This PPA now has packages available for all versions of Ubuntu from Precise to Cosmic!

Comment: Hey, I'm maintaining this PPA. Please ping me if I forget to update it for new versions. As for the question of whether to trust PPAs: Launchpad builds the packages from source. So, if you run `apt-get source <package>`, that's the exact code I uploaded. If you don't trust me, compare the `.orig` file to the upstream sources. :) Also, I upload the build files to [GitHub](https://github.com/YtvwlD?tab=repositories&q=&type=&language=perl).

Answer (score 3):

Note that there's now an unofficial ASCIIquarium distribution on the Snap Store:

[image: Get it from the Snap Store]

Disclaimer: I am the snap publisher :).